# How many $2020$-digit-numbers divisible by 3 satisfying the digits are $2, 4, 5, 7$ and digits $4, 5$ must not stand next to one another are there?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

> Determine how many $2020$-digit-numbers simultaneously satisfy these three constraints:
>
> **i/** every digit of the number is one of the following: $2, 4, 5, 7$;
>
> **ii/** digits $4$ and $5$ must not stand next to one another;
>
> **iii/** the number is divisible by $3$.

Let $x_n, y_n, z_n, t_n$ be the number of $n$-digit-numbers that end with $2, 4, 5, 7$ respectively $(n \in \mathbb Z^+)$.

We have that $x_n + y_n + z_n + t_n = S_n$.

(with $S_n$ being that number of $n$-digit-numbers that satisfy the first two conditions of the problem).

It can be seen that $t_n = x_n, y_n = z_n \implies \left\{ \begin{align} x_{n + 1} &= x_n + 2y_n\\ y_{n + 1} &= S_n\\ S_{n + 1} &= 2(x_n + y_n) \end{align} \right. \implies S_{n + 2} = 3S_{n + 1} + 2S_n$.

There exist constants $p$ and $q$ such that $S_n$ can always be expressed in the form of $p\alpha^n + q\beta^n$ for $\forall n \in \mathbb Z^+$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the equation $x^2 - 3x - 2 = 0$.

Furthermore, it can be obtained that $S_1 = 4$ and $S_2 = 10$.

$\implies \left\{ \begin{align} \alpha + \beta &= 3\\ \alpha\beta &= - 2\\ p + q &= 4\\ p\alpha + q\beta &= 10 \end{align} \right.$ $\implies \left\{ \begin{align} (\alpha, \beta) = \left(\dfrac{3 + \sqrt{17}}{2}, \dfrac{3 - \sqrt{17}}{2}\right)\\ (p, q) = \left(2 + \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{17}}, 2 - \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{17}}\right)\end{align} \right.$

$$ \implies S_n = 2\left[\left(1 + \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{17}}\right) \cdot \left(\dfrac{3 + \sqrt{17}}{2}\right)^n + \left(1 + \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{17}}\right) \cdot \left(\dfrac{3 - \sqrt{17}}{2}\right)^n \right]$$

Comment: How do you get $y_n+1=S_n$?  How is it possible that all but one of the numbers ends in $4$?  I don't understand the other equations either.  We have $S_n=2(x_n+y_n)$ not $S_{n+1}$.  Even if the equations were correct, how would they help, since you aren't enforcing condition iii?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Why doesn't $2018$ $4$'s followed by $2$ $2$'s work?  Sum of the digits is $8076\equiv0\pmod{3}$  Am I missing something?

Comment: Are we looking for numbers satisfying all three conditions together, or separately for each one?

Comment: I have obtained the same  recurrence relation as you (although I don't follow your argument).  However, it's probably messy to adapt this method for the third condition.

Answer (score 1):

**This is an answer to your question about solving the recurrence relation.**

The method of solving a linear recurrence relation such as yours is as follows.

Solve $x^2-3x-2=0$. This has roots $\frac{3+\sqrt {17}}{2}$ and $\frac{3-\sqrt {17}}{2}$.

Then $S_n=A\left(\frac{3+\sqrt {17}}{2}\right)^n+B\left(\frac{3-\sqrt {17}}{2}\right)^n$ for constants $A$ and $B$.

The constants can be found from the values of $S_1$ and $S_2$.

**Obtaining your recurrence relation**

There were some queries about your derivation of this. However, it can be obtained as follows.

$$x_{n+1}=t_{n+1}=S_n$$
$$y_{n+1}=S_n-z_n, z_{n+1}=S_n-y_n$$

Therefore
$$y_{n+1}+z_{n+1}=2S_n-y_n-z_n$$
$$S_{n+1}-2S_n=2S_n-(S_n-2S_{n-1})$$
$$S_{n+1}=3S_n+2S_{n-1}.$$

Comment: There is still the third condition that is left unsolved.

Comment: It should be **very** close to $S_n/3$.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this, in a different way. I think that this approach works but is very long:

Let $x_{n,k}, y_{n,k}, z_{n,k}, t_{n,k}$ be the number of $n$-digit-numbers that end with 2,4,5,7 respectively, and are congruent with $k=0,1,2 \pmod{3}$.

Let $S_{n,k}=x_{n,k}+y_{n,k}+z_{n,k}+t_{n,k}$.

The problem asks you to find $x_{2020,0}+ y_{2020,0}+z_{2020,0}+t_{2020,0}=S_{2020,0}$.

Now, by checking what happens modulo 3 when you add a digit at the end of each relation you have, YIKES,
$$x_{n+1,0}= S_{n,1}     \\
x_{n+1,1}=  S_{n,2}    \\
x_{n+1,2}=  S_{n,0}    \\
y_{n+1,0}=  x_{n,2}+y_{n,2}+t_{n,2} =S_{n,2}-z_{n,2}   \\
y_{n+1,1}=  x_{n,0}+y_{n,0}+t_{n,0}= S_{n,0}-z_{n,0}     \\
y_{n+1,2}=  x_{n,1}+y_{n,1}+t_{n,1} =S_{n,1}-z_{n,1}     \\
z_{n+1,0}=  x_{n,1}+z_{n,1}+t_{n,1}=S_{n,1}-y_{n,1}    \\
z_{n+1,1}=  x_{n,2}+z_{n,2}+t_{n,2}=S_{n,2}-y_{n,2}      \\
z_{n+1,2}=  x_{n,0}+z_{n,0}+t_{n,0} =S_{n,0}-y_{n,0}     \\
t_{n+1,0}=  S_{n,2}    \\
t_{n+1,1}=  S_{n,0}   \\
t_{n+1,2}=  S_{n,1} \\$$

This leads to the system of recurrences:
$$S_{n+1,0}=2S_{n,1}+2S_{n,2}-y_{n,1} -z_{n,2} \\
S_{n+1,1}=2S_{n,2} +2S_{n,0}-z_{n,0}-y_{n,2}    \\  
S_{n+1,2}=2S_{n,0}+2S_{n,1}-z_{n,1} -y_{n,0} \\
y_{n+1,0}=  S_{n,2}-z_{n,2}   \\
y_{n+1,1}=  S_{n,0}-z_{n,0}     \\
y_{n+1,2}=  S_{n,1}-z_{n,1}     \\
z_{n+1,0}=  S_{n,1}-y_{n,1}    \\
z_{n+1,1}=  S_{n,2}-y_{n,2}      \\
z_{n+1,2}=  S_{n,0}-y_{n,0}   $$

or
$$\begin{bmatrix}
S_{n+1,0} \\
S_{n+1, 1}\\
S_{n+1,2} \\
y_{n+1,0} \\
y_{n+1,1}\\
y_{n+1,2} \\
z_{n+1,0} \\
z_{n+1,1}\\
z_{n+1,2} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0& 2 & 2 & 0 & -1 & 0 &0 & 0 & -1 \\
2& 0&2 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 2 &  0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0& -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 &  0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 &0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
S_{n,0} \\
S_{n, 1}\\
S_{n,2} \\
y_{n,0} \\
y_{n,1}\\
y_{n,2} \\
z_{n,0} \\
z_{n,1}\\
z_{n,2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Which is a linear recurrence in 9 variables. Solving it boils down to calculate a high power of the coefficient  matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0& 2 & 2 & 0 & -1 & 0 &0 & 0 & -1 \\
2& 0&2 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 2 &  0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0& -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 &  0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 &0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

**The computations can probably be made more managable by finding extra relations between $S_{n,k}, y_{n,k}, z_{n,k}$.**

Comment: That is impressive. But it can't use as a viable option in test settings. That's sad.